# Changing positions about 10 people around a circular table

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider 10 people sitting around a circular table. In how many different ways can they change seats so that each person has a different neighbor to the right?

I'm not sure about my answer. It is an exercise from the book *The Art and Craft of Problem Solving*.
My thought is to fix 1, while consider its left side, can not be 10, so it has 8 choices, and count them left to left, we get 8!. While if the final one is 2, then it is incorrect. Eliminate this situation, I think the answer is 8!-7!.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It is not as simple as you are thinking.  Person $i + 1$ cannot be to the right of person $i$, where $1 \leq i \leq 9$ and person $10$ cannot be to the right of person $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Solving this for smaller number of people, I get $a_1=0$, $a_2=0$, $a_3=1$ (132), $a_4=1$ (1432), and $a_5=8$ (13254, 13524, 13542, 14352, 14253, 15243, 15324, 15324, 15432).

Sticking those into OEIS, I got https://oeis.org/A000757, which gives us $a_{10}=120288$.  It suggests that a recurrence relation is

$$a_n = (n-2) a_{n-1} + (n-1) a_{n-2} - (-1)^n$$ which the interested reader could verify.

Comment: @saulspatz I updated my answer with a link to the correct OEIS sequence.